# Why is my bulk replace function not working?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a function that uses the underscore.js each function to just call a string replace on each item in a list. (Actually a pair of lists):

```
//Base object
buckets = {
  counters: ["stats.REPLACE.msg_delivered",
              "stats.REPLACE.delivery_failed"],
  timers: ["stats.timers.REPLACE.msg_delivery_timer.median",
            "stats.timers.REPLACE.msg_delivery_timer.mean",
            "stats.timers.REPLACE.msg_delivery_timer.std",
            "stats.timers.REPLACE.msg_delivery_timer.upper"]
};

//function in question
_getNodeTargets = function(node) {
  var targets = buckets;
  _.each(targets.counters, function(bucket) { bucket = bucket.replace("REPLACE", node);});  
  _.each(targets.timers, function(bucket) { bucket = bucket.replace("REPLACE", node);});
  return targets;
}
```

I can step into the each function and see that the strings are being replaced and assigned back to bucket. However, when I hit the return the targets object is unchanged with REPLACE still in each of the strings.

I have no doubt I am doing something dumb but for whatever reason I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since bucket is just a string, it is not a reference and therefore changing it does not change what was stored in the array. You'll need to change it directly on the array by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make use of the other arguments `_.each` gives your callback:

```
_.each(targets.counters,
      function(bucket, i, target) {
          target[i] = bucket.replace("REPLACE", node);
      });
```

The reason for this is that `bucket` itself is a reference to a string; replacing that reference with one of your own does not also replace the reference stored in the collection (that keeps pointing to the unmodified version). In contrast, `target[i]` does go and update the collection so the change is visible even after your callback returns.